# Receiving a refund for AA Transportation Vouchers after using them for a flight paid with a credit card

Tags: airlines, cancellations, american-airlines, refunds, vouchers

I had to cancel a flight and American Airlines mailed me a Transportation Voucher Exchange Coupon.

I ordered new tickets that I wanted to pay with the coupons, put them on hold, called American Airlines and they told me to mail the vouchers to Dept # 109. I needed to confirm my new flight tickets and paid for them with my credit card 1 month ago.

I expect to be refunded on my credit card once the coupons are accepted for payment of the flights. I have not heard anything yet from American Airlines. On the Refund Status page on the American Airlines Website it has a place where you can check your status. It is not complete.

I was just wondering, how long can I expect before I get a refund?

Comment: The question as it is right now is very hard to understand. For example it is not clear if you are referring to a flight booking (the "voucher" part suggests "yes", the "ticket stub" part suggests "no"). Please edit your question and provide further details: (1) you want to know if the voucher is accepted for *what*? Booking a new flight? (2) What is the "review and submit section"? In case of a flight booking, do you mean that your e-ticket has not been issued yet? (3) What ticket stubs did they ask for? (4) Where on the website is it? (5) Have you tried calling them?

Comment: I had to cancel a flight and American Airlines mailed me a Transportation Voucher Exchange Coupon, I ordered new tickets, put them on hold, called American Airlines and they told me to mail the vouchers  to Dept # 109.  I also confirmed my new flight tickets and paid for them with my Credit Card.  This was 1 month ago.  I have not heard anything yet.  On the Refund Status page on the American Airlines Website it has a place where you can check your status.  It is not complete.  I was just wondering how long this takes to get a refund?

Comment: Basic questions: a) your original flight reservation was presumably non-refundable? (else, you could and should simply insist on being refunded to your CC, and dispute with your CC if they refuse) b) How much were the vouchers? $25, $100 or what? c) What is "American Airlines Dept #109" supposed to mean, some compensation dept? (Initially I thought you were tellng us your own work address.)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [AA Transportation Vouchers master thread](http://www.flyertalk.com/forum/american-airlines-aadvantage-pre-consolidation/578068-transportation-voucher-vouchers-mco-faq-master-thread-consolidated.html) on Flyertalk:

> *How long does it take to process the vouchers?*
>
> **After they receive the vouchers, AA will process them within 1-3 days**, so it's really dependent on how long it takes the mail to
>   arrive to Florida. It is recommended that if you need to ticket within
>   2 weeks that you go directly to an Airport Ticket Office, who can
>   process your vouchers immediately.

Since you've been waiting for a refund for so long I would recommend [sending AA a tweet](https://twitter.com/AmericanAir) with your record locator or ticket number, it's probably stuck somewhere in the system.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have gone through vouchers will never be applied to flights already paid for.  To do so would require you to cancel your reservations.  You would loose those flights, seats ect and if there are not other available ones.  You will not get where need to.  The BIG thing is you will not get the same price either.  Tickets cost more as each day goes by.  Another thing is each person you talk to tells you a different interpretation of the rules until its to late and your are pulling your hair out.  The only way to use vouchers is to book in person.  Might be able to mail them 2 weeks in advance with a return receipt to where they would have to sign for them an then call them but who knows on that ideal.

Answer (score 0):

If you paid in full for the tickets, then mailed the vouchers, that is not the correct process and, very sorry, you may have lost the voucher.

The correct process is:

1. Make you booking and put the reservation on 24 Hour Hold.
2. Call AA Reservations and tell them you have a Voucher.
3. They will take the Voucher number and Credit Card for any balance.
4. Mail the Voucher.
5. The Ticket, which is not the same thing as a Reservation, will be issued once the Voucher is received.

At this point, likely you only option is to call AA Reservations or Customer Service and try to get the Voucher back.  They will *not* apply it to an already issued Ticket and will *not* issue a refund.

When mailing a Voucher, I always pay the extra $1 to get a tracking number from the Post Office.